# How to change url as parameter will look like controller name in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Currently the url in the address bar displays as

```
example.com/?City=Canada&para1=&para2=&....
```

Is it at all possible to make the url be:

```
example.com/Canada/?para1=&para2=&....
```

Following route is being used:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But is it possible to do this without creating "Canada" Controller or Action Method?
It should also do the same thing as the first url does.

Comment: Show the relevant controller code along with the current routes in your `RoutesConfig`

Comment: @haim770, question is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place something like the following *before* your current default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CityDefault",
    url: "{city}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Essentially, this just says that the first path in the route constitutes a "city" param. So, in a route like `/Canada/`, `city` would be "Canada", and `controller`/`action` would be the defaults of "Home" and "Index" (since they weren't provided in the route).

*Note: You are aware Canada is not a city right?*

Comment: Of course he meant Little Canada, MN. http://www.ci.little-canada.mn.us/

Comment: The above is working. But I am trying this to be applied to only one Action method in Controller. Can we do this in Attribute Routing...?